# How to get insights (traffic etc) for github gist?

Tags: github, gist

Getting 'insights' for a repository on github is very straight forward (go to repository url, click 'Insights', go to any section of interest (e.g. traffic etc).

i.e.

[image]

How can we see similar stats for a github gist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see, no, there is no traffic recorded for [a Gist](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-gists).

The only recent evolution regarding Gist are:

- "[Gist notifications](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-08-gist-notifications/) " (May 2019)
- "[Authors subscribed to gists](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-06-03-authors-subscribed-to-gists/) " (June 2019)

Thanks to the [OP stevec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5783745/stevec)'s own [query to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844191/how-to-get-insights-traffic-etc-for-github-gist/57846032#comment113034465_57846032), the official answer is (Sept. 2020):

> I'm afraid we do not currently have this feature

Comment: Hi VonC. I was thinking about starting a bounty on this question, as I find myself wondering about it frequently. Do you think a bounty would be a waste of time or worth a shot?

Comment: @stevec Not sure, considering the feature is not available, which means you would rely on a Stack Overflow user/reader to post here their own implementation/service (assuming such a service is even possible)

Comment: Thanks VonC! I think if github doesn't make them public somehow (through the web UI, or API, or somewhere else), then I think no one else would be able to provide those kinds of statistics. I wrote an email to github support, worth a shot. I'll reply back (either way) when I hear back

Comment: Got a reply: "I'm afraid we do not currently have this feature.". At least we know for sure. Hopefully some time in the future

Comment: @stevec Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.